# How to parse string in the format "20150129163809" to datetime?

Tags: c#

I my application I need to convert a string in the datetime format as below:

```
var k=    DateTime.Parse("20150129163809");
```

But its throwing up an error message that *"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."*

But, when I do

```
DateTime.Parse("2015-01-29 16:38:09")
```

its working fine...

What could be wrong?

Comment: Look at `.ParseExact()`

Comment: You need to custom parse the string into the form you expect in the second example. There is no other way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to parse well-formatted strings:

```
var k = DateTime.ParseExact("20150129163809","yyyyMMddHHmmss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`DateTime.Parse` is fairly limited in its capabilities and does not try and "guess" what format the string is in.